# Compile inline sass with npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, sass

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I've tried using sass, node-sass, and tinysass, and nothing works. I just want to compile inline sass in javascript, something like this:

```
import sassPkg from 'sass-pkg'

const style = `body{ .container{ color: red } }`
const result = sassPkg.compile(style)
```

It seems like this should be easy to do but it's not. I'd also be willing to settle for loading the sass from an external file, but I really don't think that should be necessary, and anyway I haven't been able to do that either.

Comment: What's wrong with the posted code?

Comment: @jabaa it's not a real npm package, I just used it to show the kind of simple API I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you read https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass?

Comment: @jabaa yes, as well as the docs for other packages. I don't see anything about what I want to do.

Comment: Can you explain why https://github.com/sass/node-sass#data doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: Well the thing with that is I can't even get node-sass to install on my Ubuntu linux build. tiny-sass-compiler and sass both give me error messages

Comment: So probably you should fix that issue.

Comment: @jabaa never mind, I think I found a workable solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)

```
import * as sass from 'node-sass';

const style = `body{ .container{ color: red } }`
const result = sass.renderSync({
  data: style
});
```